# Is there a way to use AWS-StartPortForwardingSession binding to all network interfaces?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, docker, portforwarding

I couldn't find a documented way, but what I'm trying to achieve is: I have a DotNetCore WebAPI I've dockerized and I'm using localport 8080 to connect to the WebAPI inside the docker to port 80. However, that dockerized image needs to connect to an ElasticSearch API which is only accessible from my localhost using AWS port forward.

The problem here is that the AWS Port forward only binds to the loop-back interface 127.0.0.1, and the docker will never be able to reach this. Is there way?

You see below localport 8991 is being forwarded to AWS remote host's ElasticSearch API listening on same port.

c:\git\event.tracking\net>netstat -ano | findstr -i 8991

TCP    127.0.0.1:8991         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       18932

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when running it in a docker (compose) container. After looking in the session-manager-plugin code, its hardcoded to localhost. The only solution was to use ie. socat:

```
socat tcp-listen:8992,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:8991
```

There is a open github issue for this as well: https://github.com/aws/session-manager-plugin/pull/54 and another hack i didnt like so much: https://github.com/aws/session-manager-plugin/issues/14#issuecomment-948519903

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer this, I will test this whenever the opportunity meets again! and come back with more comments!